# Layperson's explanation of Euler's formula

Tags: periodic-functions

A few weeks back I [asked a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699531/on-the-graph-of-fx-ix-being-sinusoidal-reasons-related-ideas-and-relevan) which lead to Euler's formula being brought up. I don't have the mathematical background to fully appreciate it's purported [mathematical beauty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_beauty).

Just yesterday I wondered about the graph of the function $(-1)^x$ and after some exploration and [research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function) was again lead back to [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

I'm wondering if someone can provide an explanation of Euler's formula sufficient to help me appreciate it in the context of periodic functions.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a layperson. I don't think there is a entirely satisfactory explanation that does not involve an understanding of the exponential function and/or differential equations. The approach you take comes down to how one defines $\cos,\sin$.

Comment: One viewpoint (not an explanation) is to consider the complex numbers with $0$ removed. Any point $z$ can be written as $z = |z| {z \over |z|}$, and $|z|$ is just a real number, and ${z \over |z|}$ is a point on the unit circle. Since $|z|>0$ we can write it as $|z|=e^x$ for some real $x$ and since ${z \over |z|}$ is on the unit circle, we can write ${z \over |z|} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ for some $\theta$ (there are many $\theta$s that will solve this, corresponding to wrapping around the circle). This gives $z= e^x(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$. Any $z\neq 0$ can be written this way...

Comment: (Cont.): This would suggest the definition $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, so we can now write $z=e^{x+i \theta}$. This is not, of course, an explanation, but might provide some insight to the relationship.

Comment: Some of the proofs here might be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-eit-cos-t-i-sin-t

Comment: @HansLundmark: Nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what functions solve the DE $y" = -y$? That is, what functions can you differentiate twice, take the negative, and get the function back?

They are $\sin(x), \cos(x), e^{ix}$. However, because the original question was a second order DE, there is only two solutions, not three. That must mean $e^{ix}$ can be written as $A\sin(x) + B\cos(x)$. Solving for those constants gets you Euler's formula.